# PHP Type-Cast Confusion

Tags: php, types

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $val = 0;
    $res = $val == 'true';

    var_dump($res);
?>
```

I always was under impression that $res should be 'false' as in the above expression PHP would try to type cast $val to boolean type (where zero will be converted as false) and a string (non-empty string is true). But if I execute the code above output will be:

```
boolean true
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: The string 'true' probably confusing a little, here is another example:

`<?php
    $val = 0;
    $res = $val == 'xxxxxx';
    var_dump($res);
?>`

Still $res -> true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, all non-empty, non-numeric strings evaluate to zero, so `0 == 'true'` is TRUE, but `0 === 'true'` is FALSE.  The string `true` has not been cast to a boolean value, but is being compared as *a string* to the zero.  The zero is left as an int value, rather than cast as a boolean. So ultimately you get:

```
// string 'true' casts to int 0
0 == 0 // true
```

Try this:

```
echo intval('true');
// 0
echo intval('some arbitrary non-numeric string');
// 0
```

Review [the PHP type comparisons table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).  In general, when doing boolean comparisons in PHP and types are not the same (int to string in this case), it is valuable to use strict comparisons.

Comment: Thank you, this is clear that with === operator result will be FALSE, but 0 is int, i can event type cast it to `$res = (int)$val == (string)'true';` and result still will be TRUE.

Comment: Sorry, I added another example to make my question more clear. I did not mean that the right operand should be 'true' it can be any string and when PHP does comparison of the string with integer 0 (zero) result is: true.

Comment: @user1393876 Yes, I address that above.  _Any_ non-numeric string when cast to an integer is 0.

Comment: Thank you Michael, this explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$val` is the first operator PHP converts the string `true` to an integer which becomes 0. As a result 0 ==0 and your result is true;

Comment: Thank you for your response, so coming from your logic, interpreter will convert type of the second operand to the type of the first operand, right?

But if I change operands the result is still true:

`<?php
    $val = 0;
    $res = 'xxxxxx' == $val;
    var_dump($res);
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $val = 1;
    $res = (bool)$val == 'true';

    var_dump($res);
?>
```